# How to reset a SwiftUI MapKit coordinate region's center when navigating to a NavigationLink?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapkit

**Is there a way to update the MKCoordinateRegion of a MapView sheet/NavigationLink on appear?**

I have a view that is being used to input some data to create a longitude/latitude combination from a street address:

### Create.swift:

```swift
@State var longitude:Double = -122.677579; // Default longitude
@State var latitude:Double = 45.515519;    // Default latitude
@State var streetAddress:String = "";      // Empty string
@State private var isShowing = false;

var body:some View {
  VStack {
    /* Take in the street address string via TextField */
    Button(action:{validate()}, label:"Next")
  }
   .sheet(isPresented:$isShowing) {
     LocationPicker(longitude:self.longitude, latitude:self.latitude)
   };
}

func validate() {
  var isValid:Bool = false;
  /*
    1. convert the street address to longitude and latitude
    2. store long/lat in self.longitude, self.latitude
    3. set isValid to true
  */
  isShowing = true;
}
```

The flow:

1. Accept a street address from the user
2. clicking the 'next' button validates the street address by converting it to longitude/latitude
3. Those longitude and latitude values are stored in the state variables
4. isShowing is set to true, bringing up the `.sheet`, which contains a `LocationPicker` view.

### LocationPicker.swift:

```swift
struct LocationPicker: View {
    @State var latitude:Double;
    @State var longitude:Double;
    var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(
        latitudeDelta: 0.009,
        longitudeDelta: 0.009
    )
    @State var region:MKCoordinateRegion;

    init(latitude:Double, longitude:Double) {
        _latitude = State(initialValue: latitude)
        _longitude = State(initialValue: longitude)
        _region = State(initialValue :MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude),
            span: self.span
            ))
    }

    var body:some View {
      Map(coordinateRegion: $region,
          showsUserLocation: false
      )
      /* ... */
    }
}
```

The issue I have with this configuration is that the `.sheet`'s `LocationPicker` in `Create.swift` gets rendered when the `Create.swift` view gets rendered. So when I pass the longitude/latitude states into the sheet's `LocationPicker`, the default values are passed, and the centerpoint that appears when the map opens is the default coordinates rather than the coordinates that are generated by the `streetAddress` in `validate()`.

I've attempted to use both an invisible `NavigationLink` and a `.sheet` in `Create.swift`, but both render at the same time as the parent. I tried using `@Binding` doubles for `LocationPicker.swift`:

```swift
struct LocationPicker: View {
    @Binding var latitude:Double;
    @Binding var longitude:Double;
    var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(
        latitudeDelta: 0.009,
        longitudeDelta: 0.009
    )
    @State var region:MKCoordinateRegion;

    init(latitude:Binding<Double>, longitude:Binding<Double>) {
        _latitude = latitude
        _longitude = longitude
        _region = State(initialValue :MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude),
            span: self.span
            ))
    }

    var body:some View {
      Map(coordinateRegion: $region,
          showsUserLocation: false
      )
      /* ... */
    }
```

However, `CLLocationCoordinate2D` does not accept `Binding<Double>` as a data type for latitude or longitude.

Comment: Did you try to use bindings in the LocationPicker and bind these properties to the ones in the main view? - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-binding-property-wrapper

Comment: @CloudBalancing yeah, unfortunately, `CLLocationCoordinate2D` doesn't accept type `Binding<Double>` for the `latitude` and `longitude` parameters. See the last code block for that implementation. Maybe I did something wrong with reading the bound values?

Comment: Did you try initializing the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` with them  as `latitude.wrappedValue` & `longitude.wrappedValue`?

Comment: Wowza. I tried this earlier and it didn't work, but I must have messed something else up along the way because I re-tried it and now it works! Repost as an answer and I can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a `Binding` in to an init, if you need to use the values contained in the `Binding`, you must use `.wrappedValue` to access the underlying values. In this case, you are passing in two `Binding<Double>` and are attempting to use them to create a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, so the initializer would have to look like this:

```
init(latitude:Binding<Double>, longitude:Binding<Double>) {
    // Binding
    _latitude = latitude
    // Binding
    _longitude = longitude
    _region = State(initialValue :MKCoordinateRegion(
                                                 // not Bindings
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude.wrappedValue, longitude: longitude.wrappedValue),
        span: self.span
        ))
}
```